# How to check the status of jobs in mule based quartz scheduler

Tags: mule, quartz-scheduler

My mule based application using Quartz Scheduler Framework. Please let me know how can i check status of my all job.

Thanks and Regards,
VADIVEL P M

Comment: What have you tried? Also, you shouldn't need to sign off on your question, your name will appear below it anyway.

Comment: It is quite unclear what you are asking, please check [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to write a good question!:)

Comment: Great Welcome to StackExchange!!!.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the link https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/managing-schedules. Assuming you are using Clouhub for deployment

As mentioned in the Link (Manage schedules at RunTime- screenshot). All your Job names are listed Under `Name`. And you can able to see  Jobs status whether it been run or not by the option `last run` (date and time).
Can  able to Modified the schedule time( or use cron expression).
More details are in the Link.

Link talks about POLL, but you can give it a go for Quartz also since both are scheduling components.